# There's a stray span showing in the Careers "Add Reading" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Steps to reproduce:

- Go to careers
- Got to profile
- Click "add an article or blog post you’ve read"

Have a look at a shy and stray span-element in it's not so natural environment. We should really catch it and bring it back into the code plains where it belongs...so, who get's the gun?

[image: A screenshot of the careers page showing a stray span-element which should not be visible]

Comment: Can't repro this on my profile: http://i.imgur.com/9ogsomn.png

Comment: @rossipedia: Not books, blog posts.

Comment: [Definitely repro](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mjEri.png).

Comment: Yup, just repro'd. Checking it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the report Time Traveling Bobby. This is fixed now.